# Running a JS test suite from a Rails environment with a fixture factory, or an API for frontend to request certain fixtures to be loaded on backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, capybara, integration-testing, factory-bot

I'm a frontend developer working with EmberJS. That's a fantastic frontend framework that adopts a lot of virtues from Rails: it's very sophisticated and opinionated and at the same time it's extremely agile and handy to use.

Ember has its own test suite perfectly capable of acceptance testing. But it either tests against a backend mock, which is bad for two reasons: it is tedious to create a functional backend mock, and it does not test frontend-backend integration. Or Ember can test against a backend running normally, which makes it impossible to use a fixture factory like FactoryGirl/Fabrication, and you'll have to manually reset the testing database after every test.

A traditional solution to this is to use Capybara. The problem with Capybara is that Ember is very asynchronous by its nature. Capybara is unable to track whether Ember has finished requesting data/calculating reactive properties/rendering GUI/etc.

There are some people using Capybara to test Ember, and all of them use ugliest hacks. Here are just a couple for you to get the foul taste of it:

```rb
patiently do
  return unless page.has_css? '.ember-application'
end

2000.times do #this means up to 20 seconds
  return if page.evaluate_script "(typeof Ember === 'object') && !Ember.run.hasScheduledTimers() && !Ember.run.currentRunLoop"
  sleep 0.01
end
```

[source](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/automated-ember-tests-in-rails-environment/3380/5?u=lolmaus)

```rb
def wait_for_ajax
 counter = 0
 while true

 active = page.execute_script(“return $.active”).to_i
 #puts “AJAX $.active result: “ + active.to_s

 break if active < 1
 counter += 1
 sleep(0.1)
 raise “AJAX request took longer than 5 seconds OR there was a JS error. Check your console.” if counter >= 50
 end
end
```

[source](https://medium.com/@thatandyrose/testing-ember-js-with-capybara-and-rspec-f793d7ddb49)

So the idea is to use the wonderful Ember's JS test suite to execute tests **from Rails**. It would allow using Factory Girl to set up the database for every test specifically... and run a NodeJS/Ember test instead of Capybara.

I can imagine something like this:

```rb
describe "the signin process", :type => :feature do
  before :each do
    FactoryGirl.create(:user, :email => 'user@example.com', :password => 'password')
  end

  it "signs me in" do
    test_in_ember(:module => 'Acceptance: User', :filter => 'signs me in')
  end

  it "logs me out" do
    test_in_ember(:module => 'Acceptance: User', :filter => 'logs me out')
  end
end
```

Ember has a command-line interface to testing that can run specific tests, based on [Testem](https://github.com/airportyh/testem).

Alternatively, Ember test suite could be used normally, but it would start every test with a call to a special API, requesting certain fixture factory definitions to be loaded.

Formal question: how do I use the best from both worlds together: native test suite from EmberJS and native fixture factory from Ruby on Rails?

Comment: You could dump the fixtures to JSON files. But they would still need to be served by some sort of server to avoid the issues with the `file://` protocol and CSR.

Comment: @papirtiger, this makes no sense. My initial goal is to test frontend-backend integration, test real backend logic dynamically, not some static API mock.

Comment: FactoryGirl is a Ruby DSL for creating factories - each factory definition is just a block of ruby code, not some static definition. If you wanted to port the dynamic aspects of a factory such as sequences etc you would have to write a parser which transpiles into javascript.

Answer (score 2):

### There are a number of issues:

1. FactoryGirl is a Ruby DSL for creating factories - each factory definition is just a block of ruby code, not some static definition. If you wanted to port the dynamic aspects of a factory such as sequences etc you would have to write a parser which translates the DSL into a javascript DSL.
2. Javascript factories would not be able to write to the database without accessing your public API's anyways.

### Some rough ideas of how this could bridged:

1. Set up fixtures before your specs - and pass them to your scripts. Most javascript drivers allow you use page.execute_script which can be used to pass a serialized fixture. Cons: must be done before test execution begins.
2. Set up a factories API which allows you to invoke factories via ajax. Preferably in a mountable Rails Engine. Cons: slow, asynchronous

---

```
def FactoriesController
   # get /spec/factories/:factory/new
   def new
     @factory = FactoryGirl.new(params[:factory_uid])
     respond_to do |f|
       render json: @factory
      end
   end

   # post /spec/factories/:factory
   def create
     FactoryGirl.create(params[:factory_uid], factory_params)
   end

   # ...
end
```

3. Create a FactoryGirl parser which still does not solve issue 2.

### added:

A crappy example factory client:

```
var FactoryBoy = {
    build: function(factory, cb){
       $.ajax('/factories/' + factory + '/new' , dataType: 'json').done(function(data){ cb(data) });
    }, 
    create: function(factory, cb){
        $.ajax('/factories/' + factory , dataType: 'json' method:'POST').done(function(data){ cb(data) });
    }
}
```

Test example:

```
module('Unit: SomeThing');

test('Nuking a user', function() {
  var done = assert.async(); 
  FactoryBoy.create('user', function(user){
     this.store.find('user', user.id).then(function(u){
       $('#nuke_user').click();
       ok(u.get('isDeleted'));
       done();
     });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but you're still missing the point, papirtiger. I've got a Rails backend with a lot of business logic. When you use the frontend, it causes the backend to do a lot of stuff under the hood. I want to test that. Just producing fixtures and serving them into the frontend in not enough. I want the fixtures to be loaded into the database so that the backend is the fully functional and is in a certain state. The problem is that each test requires a a fresh (and unique!) initial state, this means that a different set of fixtures has to be loaded into the backend for every test individually

Comment: No, read the answer again.  Both of my suggestions involve persisting factories. The first solution would require you to set up any fixtures required for that specific test before running the javascript test. The second using a plain old REST api to create factories from your javascript tests. Combine this with DatabaseCleaner to wipe the test DB after each spec.

Comment: Okay, so we're talking about having a backend running in test mode and populating it with fixtures for every test. In my question, I've outlined two possible ways: 1) starting tests from Rails, populate fixtures normally, then somehow execute JS tests and collect reports; 2) starting tests from JS, use some special API to tell the backend which fixtures to load before every tests. Your 2nd solution seems to be the same as my 2nd. The only difference is that I never need to serve fixtures via GET, I only need to tell the backend which fixtures to load, then work with the backend via normal API.

Comment: But I still need details on implementation of the 2nd way. How do I make the controller available only in test mode? How do I purge the old data before populating the database with new fixtures? Etc. I will happily accept your answer if you elaborate and I manage to reproduce it in a boilerplate Rails app.

Comment: As for the rest of your answer, we still seem to have misunderstanding. "Javascript factories would not be able to write to the database without accessing your public API's anyways." -- I DO want the frontend to use normal API during tests. That's the point of integration testing.

Comment: What I meant is that fixtures and factories are used when you just want some records to be in the database before the test starts and not have to be bothered with for example confirmation steps or authorization (which you would have to deal with if your factory was just a javascript port of a RSpec factory and had to go though through your regular API).

Comment: How do I purge the old data? Use [DatabaseCleaner](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner). Provided you are invoking each javascript test from RSpec in its own example block database cleaner will wrap each test in a transaction and rollback the transaction after the test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78176/discussion-between-papirtiger-and-lolmaus-andrey-mikhaylov).